# Applying Compactness Theorem in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic

$A$ is a first-order sentence over the language $L = [; R, =]$ where $R$ is a binary predicate symbol. Suppose that for each $n \geq 3$, $A$ has a model consisting of a directed cycle with n nodes, where $R$ represents the edge relation of a directed graph. Prove that $A$ has a model whose universe $M$ includes an infinite path; i.e. a set of distinct elements $v_0, v_1, ...$ such that $R^M(v_i, v_{i+1})$ holds for all $i \geq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma$ be a set of sentence of the form

$$
\sigma_n = [\forall x_1 \forall x_2\cdots \forall x_n : R(x_1,x_2)\land \cdots \land R(x_{n-1},x_n) \to \exists y R(x_n,y)\land \bigwedge_{1\le i\le n} x_i\neq y].
$$

and let define $\tau=[\exists x\exists y :R(x,y)\land x\neq y]$.

Since $\{A,\tau\}\cup \{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots , \sigma_n\}$ has a model (consider the model of $A$ consisting of a directed cycle with $n+1$ nodes), there is a model of $\{A,\tau\}\cup \Sigma$, by compactness theorem.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a model of $\{A,\tau\}\cup \Sigma$. Since $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\tau$, there is a distinct $c_0,c_1\in \mathfrak{A}$ satisfy that $(c_0,c_1)\in R^\mathfrak{A}$. If there is a distinct $c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_{n-1}\in \mathfrak{A}$ satisfy
$$(c_0,c_1),(c_1,c_2),\cdots,(c_{n-2},c_{n-1})\in R^\mathfrak{A},$$
then by sentence $\sigma$ there is $c_n$ that distinct from $c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_{n-1}$ and satisfy $(c_{n-1},c_n)\in R^\mathfrak{A}$. So the set $\{c_n:n=0,1,2,\cdots\}$ is an infinite path over $\mathfrak{A}$.